# Phonegap CLI: "Upload failed You need to add an icon to your APK phonegap"

Tags: android, cordova, icons, command-line-interface

I have created an application for upload in with phonegap 3.5.0. I used the "Icons and Splash Screens" guide to create application icons, and they show up when running through debugging in the AVD and my phone. When I create the APK for upload to Google Play, however, I am prompted with "Upload failed
You need to add an icon to your APK."

What do I need to change the manifest file to in order for the be able to upload? Or is the error somewhere else? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: have you checked if the icons are in the correct folder?

Comment: What folder should the files be in? I created the res/android/ldpi.png (& mdpi, hdpi folders too) and posted icons in them. I build the application in CLI and it moved them to platforms/android/res/ and the corresponding folder for each size-- drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi. Inside those is png files named icon.png.

Comment: I don't know what could be the correct folder, I don't have too much experience with Phonegap. But those folders are used for imgs of the app. Try to search something like ic_launcher.png (it would be outside those folders, probably at the main folder)

Comment: One question, 'res/android' or 'android/res'? I just created a project and the correct path is `platforms/android/res/drawable-*`

Answer (score 0):

In your config.xml file > add your icons
Make sure that you placed the icon image in the folder res/android/

```
 <platform name="android">
          <icon src="res/android/ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
          <icon src="res/android/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
          <icon src="res/android/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
          <icon src="res/android/xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
 </platform>
```

for more information http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/config_ref_images.md.html